# Does drinking alcohol through a straw make you drunk quicker?

Tags: alcohol, drinks

It is said that drinking alcohol through a straw gets you drunk faster. For example, [The Drunk Pirate](http://www.thedrunkpirate.com/2008/11/07/how-to-get-drunk-fast/http://www.thedrunkpirate.com/2008/11/07/how-to-get-drunk-fast/)

> I have absolutely no scientific explanation for why drinking alcohol through a straw gets you drunk so fast. It just does. Now granted there’s no way in hell to look cool drinking out of a straw. But if you go to a bar and order a Jack and Coke, ask for a straw. Not the little red stirring straw that comes in in the drink, a big honkin’ McDonalds straw. Start sucking your drinks up through one of those things and you’ll be invisible in about half an hour.

I've tried it and I feel like it works, but it could just be a placebo.

Comment: does a straw make you drink faster in general?

Answer (score 11):

The theory behind this is that

1. Ethanol resorption can occur in the
   mouth (which is true)
2. Orally absorbed ethanol
   doesn't pass first through the
   liver, yielding a higher
   bioavailability (which is at least to be expected considering the anatomy of the local blood vessels)
3. Drinking with a
   straw is supposedly slower, allowing
   the ethanol a longer contact time
   with the oral mucosa (which at best sounds plausible but hardly evident).

However, studies appear to contradict this. According to the book "[Alkohol und Alkoholfolgekrankheiten](http://books.google.de/books?id=-GroRJnvzXIC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)" by Singer/Teyssen (in German, sorry), studies during wine degustations (where ethanol is brought in contact with the oral mucosa but not swallowed), there was [no relevant rise in blood alcohol levels](http://books.google.de/books?id=-GroRJnvzXIC&pg=PA557&lpg=PA557&dq=resorption%20ethanol%20strohhalm&source=bl&ots=d40lGewj1W&sig=v3jFirBNroXDDtvGQtSwY4PbC9o&hl=de&ei=nqvLTZKnDcrRsgaIzJnbAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q&f=false), unless contact was for more than one hour (and then only to a BAC of 0.015).

They conclude that a stronger buzz after drinking ethanol through a straw has never been scientifically observed.